# run a simple aggregation query with spring data

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I want to run this simple query using Spring Data.

```
db.collectionname.aggregate(
    { $group: {
         _id: { group_name: "$col1" },
         'total_sum': { $sum: 1 }
    }}
);
```

I went through several articles on SO, but can't find a way to execute this query. Is it possible to run this query using SpringData then how?

Answer (score 0):

it is like below :

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                group("col1").count().as(
                        "count"));
AggregationResults<DBObject> aggregate = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
                aggregation, CollectionClass.class, DBObject.class);
        List<DBObject> mappedResults = aggregate.getMappedResults();
```